# NodeJS cluster scheduling policy

Tags: node.js, http, centos

I develop highloaded application built on NodeJS that works on centos (Linux). It has some incoming long-living connections inside. Currently I use [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/cluster.html) with [scheduling policy](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy):

```
cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_NONE;
```

because it has some advantages in productivity for me.

Also I use express.js framework in worker process to handle requests.

My question is how does operating system dispatch the HTTP requests to workers? Is there a way to queue requests somewhere behind the worker?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can manually control distribution of incoming connections(sockets) using `pauseOnConnect:true` [option](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener). So you can

> queue requests somewhere behind the worker